# How to play video from connected USB device

Tags: android, usb, usb-drive

I want to get path of USB device folder. i am getting info of pendrive from following code

```
 private void showDevices() {
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
            mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            //your code

            Log.e("usb", "name: " + device.getDeviceName() + ", " +
                    "ID: " + device.getDeviceId());
            mInfo.append(device.getDeviceName() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getDeviceId() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getDeviceProtocol() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getProductId() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getVendorId() + "\n");
            path = device.getDeviceName();
        }
    }
```

but when i want to get file from USB storage i am getting this error file not found exception open failed eacces

if (new CheckForSDCard().isSDCardPresent()) {

```
        apkStorage = new File(device.getDeviceName()
                + "/"
                        + Utils.downloadDirectory);
    } else if (!apkStorage.exists()) {
        apkStorage.mkdir();

    }
    outputFile = new File(apkStorage, "demo.mp4");
    try {
        byte[] b = new byte[(int) outputFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
        fileInputStream.read(b);
        byte[] yourKey = Encryption.generateKey("password");
        byte[] decodedData = Encryption.decodeFile(yourKey, b);
        File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();

        outputFile = File.createTempFile("videoFile", ".mp4", outputDir);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        fos.write(decodedData);
        fos.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        //Read exception if something went wrong
        e.printStackTrace();
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
        String s = writer.toString();
        Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        outputFile = null;

    }`
```

Comment: `path = device.getDeviceName();` Which value of `path` do you get?

Comment: /dev/usb/002 sometimes change last value @greenapps

Comment: Have you looked with a file explorer app on your device if this 'path' exists? Why do you think that a device name would be a file system path?

Comment: i am confused how to get path i think device name itself is path but it is wrong so my question is how i can get path

Comment: Is there a path? If there is you could discover it with a file explorer app on your device. Are you ever browsing around with such apps? You should! Know your device! Look in `/mnt` and `/storage`. And the second or third path delivered by `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Comment: But yet better do not try to write to paths. To files. Use the Storage Access Framework instead. Adapt to modern times.